# What is the correct syntax for Task.Factory.StartNew?

Tags: vb.net, syntax-error

I am trying to start a new thread in VB.NET and I'm having syntax problems.

In C# this is how we can do the same task using:

```
var manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
waitHandles.Add(manualResetEvent);
var taskOne = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new Thread(TaskToRun).Start(manualResetEvent));
taskOne.Wait();
```

`TaskToRun` is a void method with a single object parameter.

All online converters generate VB.NET code similar to this:

```
Dim manualResetEvent = New ManualResetEvent(False)
waitHandles.Add(manualResetEvent)
Dim taskOne = Task.Factory.StartNew(Function() New Thread(AddressOf TaskToRun).Start(manualResetEvent))
taskOne.Wait()
```

Comment: Why create a Task that starts a Thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no reason to start a Task that does nothing but launch a Thread.  You should just create the Task directly.  You should be able to do that in VB via:

```
Dim manualResetEvent = New ManualResetEvent(False)
waitHandles.Add(manualResetEvent)
Dim taskOne = Task.Factory.StartNew(Function() TaskToRun(manualResetEvent))

taskOne.Wait() ' Blocks until task is complete
```

If you want to force the Task to use a dedicated thread, you can do so by passing the [LongRunning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions.aspx) hint.  With the default TaskScheduler, this will start the task on a dedicated thread (instead of the ThreadPool).

---

For reference, the equivelent C# would be:

```
var manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
waitHandles.Add(manualResetEvent);
var taskOne = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => TaskToRun(manualResetEvent));

taskOne.Wait();
```

Comment: The purpose was to create multiple threads and use a waithandler list to be notificed when all threads have completed running

 var waitTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => WaitHandle.WaitAll(waitHandles.ToArray()));
            waitTask.Wait();

Comment: @Sammy: If that's the case, just create multiple *Tasks*, and then call Task.WaitAll(tasks).  No need for wait handles and manually created threads.